# Ordering divs with javascript

Tags: css, html, position

I have something like this:
http://s9.postimg.org/wwizuwnq7/Untitled_1.png

And if you see, the divs (Where I marked in green) have a space of some pixel.
And i want if there is a 0-20 pixel space between divs, to order them like this:
http://s23.postimg.org/ky2htcpt7/image.png

So, i started to do this on javascript and i dont know to to continue..

```
var position = new Array();
$(".post").each(function(){
    position[$(this).attr("id")] = $(this).offset().top - $(window).scrollTop();
});
```

now i have all the position of all the divs, and now i need to check where divs have a space of 0 - 20 pixel, and then i want to take down the higher block.

I not sure if this is the good way, and if now, i need another idea..

Thanks!

Comment: Can you give a jsFiddle with your code please?

Comment: It's in php.. so i can't do this...

Comment: possible duplicate of [div under div - dont know how to do this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17698909/div-under-div-dont-know-how-to-do-this)

Comment: no, this is onother question...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this by adding a container div around the bottom 2 blocks. That way they will always be in line, regardless of the height of either of the top two blocks. You should try not to use javascript for styling. CSS is very powerful.

Here's a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/kVn7x/

**HTML:**

```
<div>
    <div style='height:100px;'></div>
    <div style='height:200px;'></div>
</div>

<div style='clear:left'>
    <div style='height:80px;'></div>
    <div style='height:80px;'></div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
div div{background:red; width:150px; display:inline-block; margin:5px; float:left; clear:none}
```

Comment: Profit is the difference in money between the amount earned and the amount spent in buying, operating, or producing something. What do you mean?

Comment: sorry, you right, i mean space. But i want this just if the space less than 20px..

Comment: Okay, do you mean the horizontal space or the vertical space between the divs? Surely you have control of this space and it does not change?

Comment: vertical, the divs need to be like this, but i want in exceptional cases. if the vertical space between the div in both the columns is less then 20 px, then bring to the same line. so if i have something like this: http://s22.postimg.org/esas8qymp/image.png it's need to be this after what i want to do: http://s24.postimg.org/v4hm6erz9/image.png

Comment: But just if the space is lees then 20 pixel, else, see the top divs. (now it's like the first photo, i want to add function to do what's happening in the second photo)

Comment: Ah, I can't imagine why you would need this, and I would recommend you rethink your layout, but I'll try a bit of JS for you in a new answer

Comment: Thanks!! i will try now to, i hope someone will find the answer!

Answer (score 1):

I managed to find a method!

```
var position = new Array();
$(".hblocks").each(function(){
    position[$(this).attr("id")] = $(this).offset().top;
});

$.each(position, function(key, value) {
    $.each(position, function(key2, value2) {
        var space = value2 - value;
        if (space <= 20 && space >= -20 && space != 0)
        {
            var finalSpace = Math.max(value, value2);
            var spaceplus = space + 28;
            if (finalSpace != value)
            {
                $("#" + key).css("margin-top",spaceplus + "px");
            }
            else
            {
                $("#" + key2).css("margin-top",spaceplus + "px");
            }
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Can't you simply add a **bottom margin** to the selected element in **CSS**?

```
#element {
   margin-bottom: 20px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your answer would be some king of javascript+css coding to verify height of elements .. work on em then re-arrange them.

Stop trying to figure out by yourself, try using [Masonry](http://masonry.desandro.com/) or [jQueryEqualHeight](http://css-tricks.com/equal-height-blocks-in-rows/)  explained on CSSTrick.

**What is Masonry?**

> Masonry is a JavaScript grid layout library. It works by placing
>   elements in optimal position based on available vertical space, sort
>   of like a mason fitting stones in a wall. You’ve probably seen it in
>   use all over the Internet.

Answer (score 0):

This is untested but something like this should work after your code...

The idea is to continuously add 1pixel to the top margin of the problematic div until the difference between the two divs is 20px

```
 while(position['div1'] - position['div2'] <20){
     $('#div2').animate({marginTop: '+=1px'}, 0);​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​
 }
```

If you want to show them directly in line as in your picture, it's even easier:

```
 var diff = position['div1'] - position['div2']
 if(diff < 20){
     $('#div2').animate({marginTop: '+=' + diff + 'px'}, 0);​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​
 }
```